# Declaring JSX element as child

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component named "TextRender" that is rendering some text:

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Text>
    {this.props.sometext}
   </Text>
  </div>
)
```

Now, I'd like to make this component render an additional JSX element that is passed as a child. Something like this:

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Text>
    {this.props.sometext}
   </Text>
  </div>

  <Text>
   {this.props.additionalJsxElement}
  </Text>
)
```

The additional JSX element would be declared in another component named "Test":

```
const additionalElement = () => {
    return (
      <div>I am the child!</div>
    )
  }
```

... and used in the component above:

```
return (
 <div>
  <TextRender additionalJsxElement={additionalElement()}></TextRender>
 </div>
)
```

Is something like this possible? Because the implementation above throws following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Comment: Seems like there is nothing wrong with your code, except possible problems with `<div>` inside `<Text>`. What's wrong then?

Comment: Ghassen Louhaichi: I updated my question with the error message. It says: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Oh I see, all you need to do is `<TextRender additionalJsxElement={additionalElement}></TextRender>`. You should pass the function component itself, without calling it with `()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about making your TextRender component a higher order component like this,

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Text>
      {this.props.sometext}
   </Text>
   <Text>
      {props.children}
   </Text>
  </div>
)
```

Then use the component like this (inject the child component as children),

```
return (
 <div>
  <TextRender>{additionalElement()}</TextRender>
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that

```
// Create the component as a function
const additionalElement =  ()=><div>I am the child!</div>;

return (
 <div>
  // pass function as a child
  <TextRender additionalJsxElement={additionalElement}></TextRender>
 </div>
)
```

In your TextRender component

```
render() {
const {additionalJsxElement, sometext } = this.props;
 return (
  <div>
   <Text>
    {sometext}
   </Text>
  </div>

  <Text>
   // the component should be made as follows.
   <additionalJsxElement/>
  </Text>
)
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately it throws this error: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: did you copy the exact thing ? note that the `additionalElement` variable should be a function which returns the jsx.

Comment: yep, I did exactly this and checked this multiple times.

Comment: In your TextRenderer component try to console.log(additionalJsxElement) and console.log(typeof additionalJsxElement)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the most idiomatic thing to do could be something like:

```
const TextRenderer = ({ someText }) => (
  <>
    <div>
      <Text>
        { someText }
      </Text>
    </div>
    { children }
  </>
)
```

You can then use it as:

```
<TextRender someText="Yoda" />

// OR

<TextRender someText="Yoda">
  Luke Skywalker
</TextRender>

// OR

<TextRender someText="Yoda">
  <div>
    Wrapped stuff
  </div>
</TextRender>
```